# Dropzone.js inside magnific popup not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js, magnific-popup

I have a magnific popup on my website and i also use dropzone.js in my popup. When i call my url directly browser there is no problem but when i call my url inside my site via magnific popup my drag&drop area doesn't load. Where is the problem?

```
<div id="nicdark_window">

<link href="http://www.dropzonejs.com/css/dropzone.css?v=1423494334" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="nicdark_archive1 nicdark_bg_grey nicdark_radius nicdark_shadow">
    <div class="nicdark_textevidence nicdark_bg_yellow nicdark_radius_top">
        <h4 class="white nicdark_margin20">Albüm Ekle</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="nicdark_margin20">
        <div class="nicdark_space20"></div>
        <form class="dropzone" action="/add-album/{{child_id}}/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
        </form>
        <script src="/template/static/js/dropzone.js"></script>
        <div class="nicdark_space20"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If i call via directly:
[image]

If i call via magnific:

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on this point? `When i call my url directly browser there is no problem but when i call my url inside my site via magnific popup`. I'm a bit confused what you mean here.

Comment: If i access page via "http://127.0.0.1:8000/add-album/2/" this url my dropzone is working but if i click button on my page (this way opens "http://127.0.0.1:8000/add-album/2/" url on magnific popup) my dropzone doesn't work

Comment: Just gonna make a guess but I think you should try and initialize dropzone manually after the popup has loaded, either in magnific popup's open / ajaxcontentloaded callbacks